# Кодек не может расшифровать файл(Python)

Tags: python-3.x

При запуске программы выдаёт такую ошибку: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte

````py
def function(foo):
    print(foo)
``` `from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email import encoders
import codecs
import PIL
import smtplib

# create message object instance
msg = MIMEMultipart()
# create message object instance
msg = MIMEMultipart()


message = "Thank you"

# setup the parameters of the message
password = "xxxxxxxx"
msg['From'] = "zp@gmail.com"
msg['To'] = "zp@gmail.com"
msg['Subject'] = "Subscription"

# add in the message body
msg.attach(MIMEImage(open("C:/png.png", encoding = 'utf-8').read()))


# create server
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')

server.starttls()

# Login Credentials for sending the mail
server.login(msg['From'], password)


# send the message via the server.
server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())

server.quit()`
````

Comment: Ну видимо потому что png и utf-8 вещи довольно перпендекулярные.

Answer (score 0):

При открытии файла, чтобы не возникало подобных ошибок, попробуйте использовать:

```py
msg.attach(MIMEImage(open("C:/png.png", 'rb').read()))
```

Файлы картинок являются бинарными файлами, поэтому попытка получения из них текста в указанной кодировке, скорее всего, вызовет ошибку.

В связи с этим, открытие файла в бинарном режиме должно помочь.